# discordpy How do I update a mongodb document?

Tags: python, mongodb, discord, discord.py, pymongo

Hello I'd like to know how to update a document in mongo I don't know how to and I'm trying to make a command that updates an item in the document

```
        check = list(warndb.warn_logs.find({"case_id": caseid}))                       
        for w in check:
            reason = w.get('reason')
            caseid = w.get('case_id')
            w.update_one(
            {"reason": reason},
            {"$set": update},
            )
            embed = discord.Embed(color=embedcolor, title="Successfully updated reason", description=f"Updated reason for case {caseid}")
            embed.add_field(name="**Before:**", value=f"{reason}", inline=False)
            embed.add_field(name="**Updated To:**", value=f"{update}", inline=False)
            embed.timestamp = datetime.datetime.utcnow()
            await ctx.send(embed=embed)
            return
```

This is the code I am using and I'm getting different errors like `TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict'` and `AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'update_one'` Please help

Answer (score 0):

You need the collection of the mongo db cluster in order to use the `update_one()` function.
Change your code to:

```py
check = warndb.warn_logs.find_one({"case_id": caseid}) #getting the document
reason = str(check['reason']) #accessing the values for reason and case_id
case_id = str(check['case_id'])
warndb.warn_logs.update_one({"case_id": caseid},{"$set": {"reason": update}}) #updating the reason
embed = discord.Embed(color=embedcolor, title="Successfully updated reason", description=f"Updated reason for case {case_id}")
embed.add_field(name="**Before:**", value=f"{reason}", inline=False)
embed.add_field(name="**Updated To:**", value=f"{update}", inline=False)
embed.timestamp = datetime.datetime.utcnow()
return await ctx.send(embed=embed) #sending the embed
```